# Non-EU countries covered under travel insurance plans for Europe

Tags: europe, insurance

I am going to Morocco this December, and as one of the requirements for applying for a tourist visa I am supposed to provide evidence of travel insurance. I searched up plans online and was surprised to find that a certain provider (Virgin Money, in case you wanted to know) covers Morocco under its 'Europe' travel insurance plans - which is cheaper than buying a worldwide plan. I wanted to know whether:

a) Is this standard practice across all travel insurance providers in the UK?

b) Which non-EU countries are covered under European travel insurance plans as the norm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certainly it depends on the company, but it is common to include popular holiday destinations that are close to Europe (such as Morocco and Egypt) within their Europe cover to be competitive.

As an example, The AA includes any country with a Mediterranean coastline as part of its Europe cover.

> The Republic of Ireland, The Continent of Europe West of the Ural
>   mountains including all countries with a Mediterranean coastline.

Columbus Direct includes Morocco and Egypt, but not Libya.

> This includes cover for travel to: Member States of the European
>   Union, Andorra, The Azores, Balearic Islands, Belarus, Bosnia, Canary
>   Islands, Channel Islands, Croatia, Egypt, Gibraltar, Iceland, Isle of
>   Man, Liechtenstein, Macedonia, Madeira, Moldova, Monaco, Montenegro,
>   Morocco, Norway, Russia (West of the Urals), San Marino, Serbia,
>   Switzerland, Tunisia, Turkey, Ukraine.
>
> Excluded Libya, Somalia, Syria, UK Cruise, Yemen.

Comment: What an insurer really cares about is the average cost of claims from travellers to a destination. Presumbally the insurers have determined that the destinations in question have a similar or lower cost than EU countries and so have included them in their Europe plans.